# Source map not loading when development server is using HTTPS and localhost

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app

I have a development server on HTTPS using a self signed certificate for locahost. App is build using create-react-app and I am starting up the dev server `set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start`. Source maps are not loaded in Chrome's developer tools.

When using HTTP source maps shows up correctly. react-scripts version is 2.1.8.